# pseudo-classes in flex css

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3, css-selectors, stylesheet

Does Flex CSS selectors support pseudo-classes?

I want to use different `backgroundColor` for a canvas based on mouse over and out. I am currently listening to `MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_OUT` events and changing the `styleName` property in the handler functions.

Is there a way I can specify `canvasStyle:hover` or something?

Comment: [Apparently it does](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors) but their wiki is severely incomplete... for instance, it doesn't say anywhere what kind of pseudo-classes are supported by which controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Flex 4 supports something called pseudo-selectors.

Pseudo-selectors use states defined in your composant.

See the [official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff2.html#WSda78ed3a750d6b8f-7b5abe51121cfcf7996-7ffd) for more info.